# Running a function in Python every time any key is pressed?

Tags: python, loops, keypress

First off, forgive me, because I'm incredibly new at this Python thing (I'm really an HTML/CSS kind of guy, but I'm trying to branch out). This is probably an elementary sort of question, but we all have to start somewhere, right?

I'm putting together a very basic Python program that will select a random letter from a string of letters and print it out every time someone hits the any key. The whole thing is pretty simple, and currently returns a random letter, but doesn't wait for a keypress to do so, and stops after completing the function runs once.

```
import random
letterlist = 'abcd'


def random_letter(letters):
    print ('Press enter for a random letter...')
    print random.choice(letters)

random_letter(letterlist)
```

Output should look like this:

```
Press enter for a random letter.
'b'
Press enter for a random letter.
```

(and so on...)

It's clear that whatever I need to do ought to fall inside of random_letter someplace. I've been googling around and have found lots of references to raw_input and mvscrt, but I'm not entirely sure what I need. It's entirely possible that I'm just asking the question wrong.

I'm assuming assuming that I need some sort of loop going on to keep this running indefinitely.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: 2.7 at the moment. Sorry, should've clarified that.

Comment: If you're using Windows, you can use `msvcrt.getch()` to wait for a single key to be pressed.

Comment: ...every time someone hits [the any key](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPDoZO5Tm_k)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you need a loop somewhere to continue prompting the user. You also need some sort of exit condition for the loop. This loop can be inside the function like so:

```
def random_letter(letters):
    while True:
        x = raw_input('Press enter for a random letter...')
        if x == 'done':
            break
        print random.choice(letters)

random_letter('abcdef')
```

Notice that inside the loop we use `raw_input` to prompt the user to type something, anything, then press enter. When the user types `done` and hits enter, we break out of the loop using `break`.

An alternative would be to wrap your existing function in a loop and take care of the prompting outside the function.

```
def random_letter(letters):
    print random.choice(letters)

while True:
    x = raw_input('Press enter for a random letter...')
    if x == 'done':
        break
    random_letter('abcdef')
```

Comment: Fantastic @Brian. After I posted this question I finally found the answer that I was looking for, here, though yours is better and the tip about having the code break is excellent. Link to previous answer: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459102/how-do-i-re-run-code-in-python

Comment: @summerteeth No problem! Just beware the difference in collecting user input from py2.x and py3.x. In python 3, `input()` is equivalent to the `raw_input()` of python 2. `input()` in python 2 will actually attempt to execute whatever the user types in as python code. This is why I originally asked about your version.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use a loop, and thinking of capturing keyboard events, then there are no cross-platform ways of doing it: [Is there a cross-platform python low-level API to capture or generate keyboard events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676713/is-there-a-cross-platform-python-low-level-api-to-capture-or-generate-keyboard-e)

For Windows, there is **pyHook**: http://pyhook.wiki.sourceforge.net/

You can look into the code of **pyKeyLogger**: http://pykeylogger.wiki.sourceforge.net/

Or a dirty way, capture interrupts: [Capture keyboardinterrupt in Python without try-except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205317/capture-keyboardinterrupt-in-python-without-try-except)